# How to limit combined result of union in mysql

Tags: mysql, limit, union

I have a MySQL table and I want all combined result to be 7 rows only

```
SELECT a.studentName, b.studentAge 
 FROM classA a INNER JOIN classB b on a.StudentID=b.StudentId
 WHERE StudentId in (
  (select StudentId from classA where studentGrade='A' limit 0,7)
  UNION
  (Select StudentId from classB where studentGrade='A' limit 0,7)
 ) limit 0,7
```

i want only 7 records in my resultset table. I am getting 7 records from first query and 7 records from second query and again trying to minimize it to 7. By the way my solution is throwing error and I am not able the resolve it. I know there is no need of union in above example but in situation I am in it do need union.
  You can also see this sql fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dcb16/12437 which demostartes some how same problem. In sql fiddle it should result first row only

Comment: What's the error message you are receiving?

Comment: @vhu actually it's showing error in first union query i.e (select StudentId from classA where studentGrade='A' limit 0,7) which works perfectly without using union

Comment: Can you show the actual error you get?

Comment: Also, you don't specify join condition for joining the tables classA and classB.

Comment: thanks for your suggetion  but i did mention join condition on studentID

Comment: Given the fiddle, please provide the desired result

Comment: The desired result is "'OpenIDM'"